# Google Sheet - Sort - Missing data and not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets

I have a very simple request, I just want to sort my sheet by 3 columns : Date, Type and Course.
I have some missing row when performing the formula on one day. I also have a problem to sort by date and the other columns. It is not sorting. I try to convert to plain text and others solutions as =SORT(ARCHIVAGE!B7:J;ARCHIVAGE!B7:B;true;ARCHIVAGE!D7:D;true;ARCHIVAGE!E7:E;true)
=SORT(ARCHIVAGE!B7:J;1;true;3;4;true) but no success at all.

[Here is a sample of the file a few days](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gSohqXB6QzjBpbE4LH91vTonkNtK0G9zoCNbYK71Lg8/edit?usp=sharing)

Thnaks for your help on this.
j.

Comment: I do not see any "missing row"s?

Comment: What data is missing? Are you trying to sort by Date, Type and Course or Client? In your formula you're sorting Date, Type and Client (Column E).

Comment: Hi, yes I try to order by date, client and course. When I do this [=SORT(ARCHIVAGE!B7:J;ARCHIVAGE!B7:B;VRAI;ARCHIVAGE!D7:D;VRAI;ARCHIVAGE!E7:E;VRAI)] then the row 6 is missing !

Comment: @Julien I don't see missing rows using your formula, also, the provided formula is sorting data starting from row 7 from the ´´´ARCHIVAGE´´´ sheet, are you trying to sort part of the data or all the rows? Another thing I noticed is that in sheet ´´´Sort´´´, location ´´´D2´´´ is a merged cell, so any data in row 2 will not show the "Course" field, you would have to unmerge that cell to show all the data.

Comment: @LorenaGomez thanks a lot this was definitely my issue

Answer (score 0):

This formula is in cell A1 of a new tab called MK_Idea:

```
=QUERY(ARCHIVAGE!B:G;"where D<>'' order by B,D,F")
```

[read about query() here](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like and use query. but here if I want to have all the values in column H I have to convert it to_text because it's a mixte of values and text.

Comment: Column H is not mentioned in your desired output

Comment: Yes but my original problem is with the SORT formula. I ignored the Query one because of this... thanks again though.